# Show $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial ^2 x}+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial ^2 y}= 4 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial{ \overline{z}}} $

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I want to solve the following exercise:

Show that:

$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial ^{2}x}+ \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial ^{2}y}= 4 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial{ \overline{z}}}.$$

My attempt:

We know that:

$$\frac{\partial}{ \partial{ \overline{z}}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right),$$

and

$$\frac{\partial}{ \partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right),$$

hence

$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial{ \overline{z}}}= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\right]= \frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\partial}{ \partial z}\left(\frac{\partial}{ \partial x}\right)+ i\frac{\partial}{ \partial z}\left(\frac{\partial}{ \partial y}\right) \right] = \frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}}{ \partial x^{2}}- i \frac{\partial^{2}}{ \partial y \partial x} + i \frac{\partial^{2}}{ \partial x \partial y} + \frac{\partial^{2}}{ \partial y^{2}}\right]= \frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}}{ \partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{ \partial y^{2}}\right].$$

Am I right? If not, can you help me fix the mistake please?

Comment: Multiple by 4. Are you right then?

Comment: well yes, that is the last step, but I want to know if the other steps were right, because I canceled out the derivatives and I don't know ...

Comment: Since we are assuming the C-R conditions, we know the 1st and 2nd derivatives are continuous. By Schwarz's theorem, the mixed partials are the same. Therefore, you subtracting the mixed partial derivatives to get zero is fine.

Comment: thanks a lot, but Are we assuming that?, well, what I posted is what the exercise says, and well, I don't know which is the shwarz theoreme. :)

Comment: Well, then everything is fine in spite the shwarz thm and the hypothesis?

Comment: Well, Can you post your mode please?

Comment: o well, right :), thanks a lot, I thought I was assuming things and this was wrong :)